# Storyboard static cells: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview, storyboard

Using storyboard, static cells, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = 
   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

always returns `nil`.

I have checked the following:

- Identifier of the cell is correctly set in IB/Storyboard and I use the same identifier in code. I verified this many times.
- I have not instantiated the view controller elsewhere (which was the problem in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797821/keep-getting-nil-from-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier)).

My view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, of course, wrapped into an *ad hoc* navigation controller in storyboard. Suspecting that my view controller somehow does not know about the cell identifiers defined in storyboard because it might be another instance, here is the code the "instantiates" it. In `prepareForSegue:`, I use

```
CustomViewController *vc = [[[segue destinationViewController] 
   viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Other customizations of the view controller done here (setting properties etc.) works fine.

I am using static cells because the number of sections and rows does not change, and each cell contains static text (and other controls or text fields to be edited).

It seems to me this is a very common task (customize static cells from storyboard in the view controller's datasource methods). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will have to show us where you actually handle creating your custom cell.  That is the important part.

Comment: I create the custom cell in storyboard. Type "Custom" and its own cell identifier. Does it not work like that?

Comment: I missed the whole static part.  Static cells are designed entirely in the storyboard.  see part 2 of this excellent tutorial www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Comment: I went through that. Why is it returning nil?

Comment: Because you can't use that with static storyboards :).  That method is for prototype style.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With static content in a table view, you do not implement any of the datasource methods (including `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so you would never dequeue the cells. There is no dequeuing for static content (that you can get involved in, anyway).

If you want to get a pointer to a particular cell:

- get it from the table view using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

  ```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  ```
- have an outlet to the specific cell and customise it directly.
- Iterate through the cells and check the `reuseIdentifier` property to get the cell you are interested in.

Any of these things can be done in viewWillAppear or similar.

If you want to have completely different content in your cells to that found on the storyboard then static cells probably aren't the right choice. You should use dynamic prototypes (note you can have multiple prototypes in the storyboard) with the traditional data source methods instead.

Comment: Thanks - so for what I want to do it seems I really need to use prototype cells. Could you add that to your answer, so I can check it? Thanks for your clarifications!

Comment: Edited my answer, you didn't actually say what you were trying to do, so hope it helps!

Comment: I am trying to have static title labels and editable text fields in some of the cells, and some other controls in others. I thought you can fill in data dynamically into static cells. The number or position of the cells does not change. I have started doing it with prototype cells, and it is so much work - almost worse than before storyboard!

Comment: Just have an outlet to each editable text field. Easy peasy. I have done this myself for a settings type screen.

Comment: That is an insane amount of work! It has got to be simpler than that. I am filling in the properties of a custom object, so it could be potentially lots of data to be processed, but mostly text in text fields. Plus, this does not work with prototype cells. - Plus I just realize, that the text fields are invisible for some reason... Storyboard nightmare!

Comment: For now, say, 8. Could be 24 in the future. I still do not understand why the cell is coming back as nil with static cells. I do not understand why the text field is not visible in prototype cells.

Comment: How about the special case of table views with mixed static and dynamic content as discussed [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/505098)?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use dataSource/delegate methods of static `UITableView`, you just don't have to **create** new cells.

If you want to modify cells with dataSource methods, inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` :

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and then start modifying cell.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but the better way to handle this is to use `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`

Comment: This is the correct answer imho.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use prototype cells rather than static cells. I am still giving the check to @jrturton as he was the first who got me the idea.

Another interesting error I just solved: with prototype cells of type "Custom", if you try to fill `cell.textLabel` with text, it will just automatically work, but all your other subviews behave very strangely. I just use my custom label now, and everything works fine.

Cheers, thanks everyone for helping out.

Comment: how did you use "Custom" Cell? because dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil?

Comment: You can specify "Custom" in Interface Builder.

Comment: I did specify Custom in Interface Builder, then I subclassed the UITableViewCell and assigned to it this cell. But it brings empty dynamic cells.

Comment: Sounds like you are not configuring them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Different to the answer above,

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

will not work. But the mentioned method to create an outlet to the `cell` itself is working.

It is also possible to place views such as `UIButtons` or `UITextFields` on the `cell` and have outlets for those as well.

Both methods can also be used in combination. E.g. set the `cell.textLabel.text` for a particular cell and have another control which will be accessed from the controls outlet.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, the Static Cells CAN'T implement the Methods in the `<UITableViewDataSource>` protocol.

So you could use the methods which ones are include in `<UITableViewDelegate>`.