# cell is always nil on a UITableView Static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController where there are three UITableViewCell static

I want to create an outlet for one of the labels inside on of the cells, I couldn't drag and drop, i read over the Internet, people suggest do the following

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.oneMenuCell.rawValue)
    let label = cell!.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label.font = UIFont(name: Constants.centuryGothic.rawValue, size: CGFloat(17))
    return cell!
}
```

i gave that label tag = 1

my problem is that the cell is always nil, though it has the correct identifer. look please
[image]

What missing did I make?

#### update

people ask for this

```
enum CellIdentefiers : String {
    case numberOfPeopleCell
    case dayCell
    case timeCell
    case preferencesCell
    case oneHistoryCell
    case oneConfirmationCell
    case oneMenuCell
}
```

Comment: Can you try using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, IndexPath)

Comment: tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

Comment: Can you show your definition of the enumeration?

Comment: @ShafKhan i got this error `'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier oneMenuCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: I think this answer has what you're looking for! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993669/storyboard-static-cells-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-returns-nil

Comment: @Austar even `ableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` gives nil :(

Comment: @Paulw11 help me please

Comment: @Austar i check that question and i kept with this nil, help me please

Comment: @ShafKhan help me please

Answer (score 0):

Your enum needs raw values i.e.

```
enum CellIdentefiers : String {
    case numberOfPeopleCell = "numberOfPeopleCell"
    case dayCell = "dayCell"
    case timeCell = "timeCell"
    case preferencesCell = "preferencesCell"
    case oneHistoryCell = "oneHistoryCell"
    case oneConfirmationCell = "oneConfirmationCell"
    case oneMenuCell = "oneMenuCell"
}
```

Comment: @sarah: with your code, what happens when you print out the value of `CellIdentefiers.oneMenuCell.rawValue`?

Comment: it will be "oneMenuCell" . that's obvious

Answer (score 0):

Reuse identifiers are for dynamic cells. To create an outlet for a label in a static cell, you *can* drag an connect an IBOutlet from storyboard to the ViewController. I just tested it and it absolutely works.

EDIT: Here is an image to prove that you can connect IBOutlets to static cell labels.

[image]

Comment: you could drag outlet from a static cell??? what xcode is your plz ? because mine not allow me

Comment: Version 7.2, but I'm pretty sure I've been doing that for awhile.

Comment: Finally figured out how to take a screenshot while holding the connecting line. I have no idea why your Xcode wouldn't let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

U need to specifically register a cell in the viewDidLoad for a given identifier:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

In your case you would do something like:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentefiers.oneMenuCell.rawValue)
```

When you access it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath u need to access that identifier "cellIdentifier" in your dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier")
```

In your case you are exactly doing that:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentefiers.oneMenuCell.rawValue)
```

The problem is these steps are generally done when you have a "custom" cell you are working with. In case you don't want to use custom cells you can simply do the following in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)
if(cel == nil){
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}
```

Lastly, @MikeAtNobel is correct. You will need to provide String values from the enum rather than int values. Hence the change suggested by him does seem valid and correct.

Comment: thanks for the ansewr but after ading your `registerClass` nothing changed, and i keep with the same error. secondly, i was already using the dequeu with identifer. third, No there is no dequeue here, this is a static cell and as I understood there is no deque here